# making recursion faster using array

Tags: python, recursion

I was trying to get this recursion faster but when I use numbers 50 and 44.4 it takes too long my desired outcome for those numbers is -800555.6302016332

```
z = int(input())
x = float(input())

def rec(n):
    global x
    l = {}
    if n == 0:
        return -1
    elif n == 1:
        return x
    elif n == 2:
        return -(x+1)/3
    else:
        if n in l:
            return l[n]
        value = float((n/x)*rec(n-1) + ((-1)**n)*((n+1)/(n-1)) * rec(n-2) + ((n-1)/(2*x))*rec(n-3)) 
        l[n] = value
        return value
print(rec(z))
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to do memoization, but using a local dictionary for that makes no sense. In each recursive call you are creating a new empty dictionary so of course the test `n in l` fails.

Comment: Yes I am trying to memorize it, could you help me how to make it work?

Comment: Create the dictionary outside of the function. Writing it so that your function is a helper function inside an outer function which is responsible for the dictionary creation is a good strategy.

Comment: You can also use `@functools.cache` to automate it.

Comment: Thanks it works, just out of curiosity how could I automate it?

Comment: `@functools.cache` is a decorator. If you put it immediately before your function definition, it will automatically transform your function into one which has been memoized. Decorators are one of the coolest things in Python -- read up on them if you aren't familiar with them.

Answer (score 1):

You are reinitializing your dictionary `l = {}` each time you recurse. Making `l` a global var should fix your problem:

```py
l = {}

def rec(n):
    global x
    global l
    if n == 0:
        return -1
    elif n == 1:
        return x
    elif n == 2:
        return -(x+1)/3
    else:
        if n in l:
            return l[n]
        value = float((n/x)*rec(n-1) + ((-1)**n)*((n+1)/(n-1)) * rec(n-2) + ((n-1)/(2*x))*rec(n-3)) 
        l[n] = value
        return value
```

You could also use `functools.lru_cache` which does memoization for you:

```py
import functools

@functools.lru_cache
def rec(n):
    global x
    if n == 0:
        return -1
    elif n == 1:
        return x
    elif n == 2:
        return -(x+1)/3
    else:
        return float((n/x)*rec(n-1) + ((-1)**n)*((n+1)/(n-1)) * rec(n-2) + ((n-1)/(2*x))*rec(n-3))
```

I would also suggest avoiding the use of global variables:

```py
import functools

def rec(n, x):

    @functools.lru_cache
    def recurse(n):
        if n == 0:
            return -1
        elif n == 1:
            return x
        elif n == 2:
            return -(x+1)/3
        else:
            return float((n/x)*recurse(n-1) + ((-1)**n)*((n+1)/(n-1)) * recurse(n-2) + ((n-1)/(2*x))*recurse(n-3))

    return recurse(n)

def main():
    n = int(input())
    x = float(input())
    print(rec(n, x))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```